# CakePhp 4 add "Content-Type: text/html" when I try to show a PDF

Tags: cakephp, download, header, cakephp-4.x

I trying to show a PDF inline but I get binary code instead. The mock  that I show below works OK in a simple php file in webroot but show binary code from an entity template.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"');    
header("Cache-control: private");
@ readfile('/opt/demo/webroot/document.pdf');
?>
```

And my layout do not have extra characters before my Headers definition:

```
<?=$this->fetch('content')?>
```

I get next information from get_headers():

> Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found [1] => Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023
> 03:42:42 GMT [2] => Server: Apache [3] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981
> 08:52:00 GMT [4] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
> [5] => Pragma: no-cache [6] => Set-Cookie:
> PHPSESSID=givi13cckql8v0oq0lnsvn2rvb; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
> [7] => Set-Cookie:
> csrfToken=wbFIJHOSq0HE1K4d0eYljTI2YzUzOWQwMTEyMGEwYjNmMTVhMmM0NTdiYmIxNjU0YTI3MTY3MzE%3D;
> path=/; HttpOnly [8] => Location:
> /login?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F107.23.196.88%2Fdocuments%2Fshow%2Ff198a0d3-ffd3-44e3-8715-8f5ed8a05185 [9] => Content-Length: 0 [10] => Connection: close [11] =>
> **Content-Type: text/html;** charset=UTF-8 [12] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [13] => Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 03:42:43 GMT [14] => Server: Apache
> [15] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT [16] => Cache-Control:
> no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate [17] => Pragma: no-cache [18] =>
> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=avupp24r2uqf66i6d95n6t5hpk; path=/; HttpOnly;
> SameSite=Lax [19] => Set-Cookie:
> csrfToken=rfiGOmviqYjfyyyyZbtXVzQ4OTAxNzc5OTc4ZjRmNmI2YmI3ZGZlOWMwYWQ5YWVjMDAyOTg2YmM%3D;
> path=/; HttpOnly [20] => Vary: Accept-Encoding [21] => Connection:
> close [22] => Transfer-Encoding: chunked [23] => Content-Type:
> text/html; charset=UTF-8 ) ?>

Is it necessary to make another change to use Headers in templates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do downloads and that vanilla PHP file have to do with fetching contents in your layout? Are you loading that PHP file in your template? Please don't do that! Also templates aren't meant to send any data at all, under no circumstances whatsoever, headers or otherwise, they just build/provide data to be used by for example controllers. Make sure to check **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files** on how to send files.

Comment: Dear @ndm. The code of my question is just a mock. In my application I'm reading files in controllers, but you are right in all. Thanks to your help, my solution is working now. As usual, the solution es to read before to code. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with Cake\Http\Response::withFile() method in this way.

```
public function show ($id){
    $path = '/home/ubuntu/receipts/' . $id . '.pdf';
    $response = $this->response->withFile($file['path']);
    return $response;
}
```

Thanks for your help @ndm